# MongoDb/mongocxx extremely slow update_one and find_one

Tags: c++, mongodb, performance, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm currently searching a good key/value store to replace our old QDBM database which is not developed anymore since years and is corrupt very often. I tried LevelDb which was quite fast, but seems to hang sometimes (which was already observed by others, maybe an internal reorganization?).

Now I'm evaluating mongodb, but the performance is really amazingly bad. mongod cpu usage goes up to over 10% while the disk usage (I'm having a SSD here) is going up maybe by one percent.

I must be doing something wrong, maybe you can help me?

Edit: With the old qdbm, we could just store key/value pairs. As I'm still comparing databases, I kept it like this although of course it would be better to have fields for every variable instead of storing whole structs as binary data.

Here are my measurements for 100k update_one and find_one:

Write Duration: 20.505634) (written: 100000, not written: 0)
Read Duration: 0.169274) (found: 0, not found: 100000)
LevelDb Open Duration: 0.018494
Write Duration: 0.380127) (written: 100000, not written: 0)
Read Duration: 0.197984) (found: 100000, not found: 0)
QDBM Open Duration: 0.006386
Write Duration: 1.293813) (written: 100000, not written: 0)
Read Duration: 1.843582) (found: 100000, not found: 0)

mongostat shows the following:
insert query update delete getmore command dirty used flushes vsize   res qrw arw net_in net_out conn time
*0    *0   4853     *0       0     1|0  0.1% 0.1%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|1 1|0  1.40m    575k    7 Jul  3 10:56:32.011
*0    *0   4955     *0       0     1|0  0.1% 0.1%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|1 1|0  1.43m    586k    7 Jul  3 10:56:33.011
*0    *0   4959     *0       0     2|0  0.1% 0.1%       1 5.65G 67.0M 0|0   1|0  1.43m    587k    7 Jul  3 10:56:34.010
*0    *0   4969     *0       0     0|0  0.1% 0.1%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 1|1  1.43m    588k    7 Jul  3 10:56:35.011
*0    *0   4996     *0       0     0|0  0.1% 0.1%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 1|1  1.44m    591k    7 Jul  3 10:56:36.011
*0    *0   5016     *0       0     1|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 1|1  1.44m    593k    7 Jul  3 10:56:37.010
*0    *0   5019     *0       0     0|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 1|1  1.45m    593k    7 Jul  3 10:56:38.011
*0    *0   5014     *0       0     1|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 1|0  1.44m    593k    7 Jul  3 10:56:39.010
*0    *0   4918     *0       0     0|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|1 1|0  1.42m    582k    7 Jul  3 10:56:40.012
*0    *0   5009     *0       0     2|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|1 1|0  1.44m    592k    7 Jul  3 10:56:41.010
insert query update delete getmore command dirty used flushes vsize   res qrw arw net_in net_out conn                time
*0  5711     24     *0       0     1|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 2|0   858k   1.35m    7 Jul  3 10:56:42.011
*0  5725     *0     *0       0     0|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 1|0   853k   1.35m    7 Jul  3 10:56:43.012
*0  5761     *0     *0       0     2|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 2|0   859k   1.36m    7 Jul  3 10:56:44.010
*0  5715     *0     *0       0     0|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 1|0   852k   1.35m    7 Jul  3 10:56:45.011
*0  5615     *0     *0       0     0|0  0.1% 0.2%       0 5.65G 67.0M 0|0 1|0   837k   1.32m    7 Jul  3 10:56:46.01

```
bool bulksetValue(const std::list<DatabaseEntry>& entries) //5 times faster, but still slow and not used in this example
{
    auto connection = mongo_access::instance().get_connection();
    if (!connection)
        return 0;

    auto collection = (*connection)["testdb"]["testcollection1"];


    mongocxx::options::bulk_write bulkWriteOptions; //force performing all operations, even if error happens
    bulkWriteOptions.ordered(false);

    auto bulk = collection.create_bulk_write(bulkWriteOptions);

    for (auto entry : entries)
    {
        mongocxx::model::update_one upsert_op{
            make_document(kvp("_id", bsoncxx::types::b_binary{ bsoncxx::binary_sub_type::k_binary, uint32_t(entry.keySize), entry.key })),
            make_document(kvp("$set",
                make_document(kvp("value", bsoncxx::types::b_binary{ bsoncxx::binary_sub_type::k_binary, static_cast<uint32_t>(entry.valueSize), entry.value })))),
        };
        upsert_op.upsert(true);
        bulk.append(upsert_op);
    }

    try {
        auto result = bulk.execute();
        printf("Matched %u and mod %u\n", result->matched_count(), result->modified_count());
        return !!result && result->modified_count() == entries.size();
    }
    catch (std::exception ex)
    {
        Logger::log(Logger::Sysinfo, Logger::Error, "Could not save in db, error: %s ", ex.what());
        return 0;
    }
}
bool set(mongocxx::collection& collection, const uint8* key, size_t keySize, const uint8* value, size_t valueSize)
{
    static options::update options;
    options.upsert(true);

    try
    {
        auto result = collection.update_one(
            make_document(kvp("_id", bsoncxx::types::b_binary{ bsoncxx::binary_sub_type::k_binary, uint32_t(keySize), key })),
            make_document(kvp("$set",
                make_document(kvp("value", bsoncxx::types::b_binary{ bsoncxx::binary_sub_type::k_binary, static_cast<uint32_t>(valueSize), value })))),
            options
        );

        auto matched = result->matched_count();
        auto mod = result->modified_count();
        return !!result;
    }
    catch (std::exception ex)
    {
        Logger::log(Logger::Sysinfo, Logger::Error, "Could not save in db, error: %s ", ex.what());
        return false;
    }
}

bool setValue(const uint8* key, size_t keySize, const uint8* value, size_t valueSize)
{
    auto connection = mongo_access::instance().get_connection();
    if (!connection)
        return 0;

    auto collection = (*connection)["testdb"]["testcollection1"];
    return set(collection, key, keySize, value, valueSize);
}


const uint8* get(mongocxx::collection& collection, const uint8* key, size_t keySize, size_t* valueSize)
{
    //hold object until next value is requested, so that we can access it on outside
    s_value = collection.find_one(
        make_document(kvp("_id", bsoncxx::types::b_binary{ bsoncxx::binary_sub_type::k_binary, static_cast<uint32_t>(keySize), key })));

    if (!s_value.is_initialized()) return 0;

    //return reinterpret_cast<const uint8*>(m_value);*/
    auto bin = s_value->view()["value"].get_binary();
    *valueSize = bin.size;
    return bin.bytes;
}

const uint8* getValue(const uint8* key, size_t keySize, size_t* valueSize)
{
    auto connection = mongo_access::instance().get_connection();
    if (!connection)
        return 0;

    auto collection = (*connection)["testdb"]["testcollection1"];
    return get(collection, key, keySize, valueSize);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto connection = mongo_access::instance().get_connection();
    if (!connection)
        return 0;

    auto collection = (*connection)["testdb"]["testcollection1"];
    collection.drop(); //we want to start with a clean database
    std::list<const uint8*> list;
    char* key;
    //prepare a list of keys
    for (uint32 i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        key = new char[7];
        uint32 keyInt1 = rand();
        uint32 keyInt2 = rand();
        
        //a simulated key, don't care about the values, those are internal restrictions
        key[0] = 2; 
        key[1] = (keyInt1 % 120) + 1;
        key[2] = (keyInt1 % 255) + 1;
        key[3] = 0;
        key[4] = 0;
        key[5] = keyInt2 / 256;
        key[6] = keyInt2 % 256;

        list.push_back(reinterpret_cast<const uint8*>(key));
    }
    
    //here time measurement starts, it takes more than 21 seconds for those 100k entries!
    const char* value = "TestDb1.0adfadfa423512345ydvykajtÃ¶o4u5690a85t09agyjredgjsdflkgxdfkjvbxkljfbkjegb";
    size_t valueLen = strlen(value);

    for (auto key : list)
    {
        done += setValue(key, 7, reinterpret_cast<const uint8*>(value), valueLen);              
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `explain` with execution statistics to find out where the time is going, add findings to the question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I only found the explain method for the shell, is something similiar existing for mongodbcxx? As you can see, I'm doing many update_one and find_one actions, will I see statistics for all executed actions or just for a single access (because that will be quite fast)?

Comment: I now added some statistics, maybe that also helps?

Comment: If your issue is with the server taking a long time to execute the queries, use the mongo shell to issue them.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running a service which needs to store its data in a database. Therefore the shell is not an option.

Comment: Use the shell to diagnose.